# How do I calculate the time at least one of a group are at work?

Tags: sampling

I need to calculate the percentage of time that one of three people are available based on:

- 253 working days (9 am - 5 pm)
- 30 days annual leave
- 8 days public holiday

So that actual days in work = working days - annual leave - public holiday.

The percentage of time that one person is available at work = (hours in work per day/hours in a day) x (working days - annual leave - public holiday)/(days in a year) = 23.5%

Assuming that the three people take annual leave randomly throughout the year how do I calculate the percentage of time that at least one of the three are at work? I would then like to see how the percentage changes as the number of people in the group increase.

Thanks for any ideas on how to do this.

Comment: This is closely related to the [Coupon Collector's Problem](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=coupon): the days of annual leave are packs of 30 coupons selected out of 253-8 = 245 non-holidays. For any given value of $n=1, 2, 3, \ldots,$ you would like to know how many coupons appeared in every one of $n$ packets collected. The thread at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/101255 gives some relevant techniques and references (although it does not directly answer your question).

Comment: Thanks whuber. I am still struggling to perform the calculation. Could anyone provide a step-by-step answer that I could use in Excel?