# Calculate probability that I have fully sampled a set

Tags: probability, sampling, coupon-collector-problem

Let's say I have a set of items out of which I  randomly take 5% . Then perform some action on these items and put them back in the set.
After how many repetitions of this process can I be 95% sure that I have performed this action on all the items.

For illustrative purposes -- Let's say I take 5 ping-pong balls blindly out from a sack where there are originally 100 white balls. I paint/repaint those I have taken red and put them back in the sack. After how many tries can I be 95% sure that all the balls in sack are now red.
What would the general form for the calculation be for other sample sizes and probabilities. (10% of balls and 75% chance etc.)

Comment: If you selected the balls 1 at a time, this would be equivalent to the coupon-collector problem; the selection of 5 at a time is a modest wrinkle on that (since you only ever get 5 different coupons in each set of 5 this way).

Comment: It might be good to edit the question and make some suggestions in the direction of at least a partial solution.

Comment: In addition to the duplicate, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/198915 is also relevant.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in a numerical result, using simulations in R

```
n=100
k=5
p=0.95

res=replicate(1e5,{
  x=rep(0,n)
  i=0
  while (TRUE) {
    x[sample(1:n,k,replace=F)]=1
    i=i+1
    if (all(x==1)) {
      break
    }
  }
  i
})

quantile(res,p)

95% 
148
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is a generalisation of the classical [coupon-collector problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem).  A reasonable way to find the solution would be to frame the process as a Markov chain.  The random variable of interest here is the hitting time for the final state in the chain.  I will suggest some basics to get you started on the problem, but you will need to have a look at material on hitting times for Markov chains to get a full solution.

To generalise your problem slightly, suppose you originally have $m$ objects in your set and you are selecting $k > 0$ random objects on each draw, via simple random sampling.  If we let $K_n$ be the number of objects that have been selected (at least once) after $n$ draws then the process $\{ K_n | n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is a discrete Markov chain with transition probabilities taken from the [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution):

$$p_{i,j} \equiv \mathbb{P}(K_{n+1} = j | K_n = i) = \frac{{i \choose k+i-j} {m-i \choose j-i}}{{m \choose k}}
\quad \quad \quad \text{for all } i \leqslant j \leqslant i+k.$$

Now, if you form the Markov chain with states $0,...,m$, starting state $0$ and transition probabilities given by this equation then the random variable you are looking for is the [hitting time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitting_time) for the state $m$.  Getting the exact distribution for the hitting time is a somewhat involved exercise (it can be done by finding the eigen-decomposition of the transition probability matrix and using this to derive the CDF for the hitting time).  Alternatively you can simulate the Markov chain a large number of times to estimate the distribution of interest.  (The other answer here gives you a direct simulation of the process, but you can probably make this more efficient by simulating the Markov chain.)

I won't go further and give a full solution, but this ought to give you an idea of the general direction we could go to try to derive the distribution of the quantity of interest.