# Quiz with questions sampled from a pool. How many new questions at each iteration?

Tags: coupon-collector-problem

I am taking a quiz which is a sample of $g$ questions from a pool of $n$ total questions. At every iteration $i$ I get a new sample of $g$ questions. **I want to know the expected number of new questions (ie questions that I have not seen before) at iteration $i$**

If $X_i$ is the random variable that models the number of new questions at iteration $i$, I would like to know $E[X_i]$. Is there a closed form for this?

- I do understand that at iteration $0$ I have $X_0=g$.
- At iteration $1$, $X_1$ is a Hypergeometric random variable with parameters $g$, $n-g$, and $n$, which are respectively the size of the sample, the number of successes, and the total number of items. Then,
  $$
  E[X_1] = \frac{g(n-g)}{n}
  $$
- At iteration $2$, I know $X_2|X_1$ which is a
  Hypergeometric random variable with parameters $g$, $n-g-x_1$, and
  $n$. Then,
  $$
  E[X_2] = \sum_{x_1} E[X_2|X_1=x_1]P(x_1)
  $$
  I guess I could compute $E[X_i]$ with:
  $$
  E[X_i] = \sum_{x_1,\dots,x_{i-1}} E[X_i|X_1=x_1, \dots, X_{i-1}=x_{i-1}]P(x_1,\dots,x_{i-1}) = \sum_{x_1,\dots,x_{i-1}} E[X_i|X_1=x_1, \dots, X_{i-1}=x_{i-1}]P(x_{i-1}|x_1,\dots,x_{i-2})\cdots P(x_1) 
  $$
  where I know all the conditional probabilities and also the expected value for $X_i|X_{i-1}\dots X_1$.

Does this sound correct? Is there any closed form for this?

I know that this is related the **Coupon collector's problem**. In particular, it is a generalization of it to **Coupons in groups of constant size** [(see page 18 in here)](https://mat.uab.cat/matmat_antiga/PDFv2014/v2014n02.pdf)

I also would like to know how far am I from the correct value if I take this  approximation:

- $E[X_0] = g$
- $E[X_1] = \frac{g(n-E[X_0])}{n} = \frac{g(n-g)}{n}$
- $E[X_2] = \frac{g(n-E[X_0]-E[X_1])}{n} = \frac{g(n-g-\frac{g(n-g)}{n})}{n}$
- $E[X_i] = \frac{g(n-E[X_0]-E[X_1]-\cdots-E[X_{i-1}])}{n}$

Comment: The answers at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/101255 will help you a great deal.  We have many threads about variations of the Coupon Collector's Problem and a large fraction of them provide relevant information.  Try [this site search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=coupon%20collector).  BTW, there are two ways to interpret your question: do you want the *initial* expectation or do you want the *conditional* expectation at each stage?  (The latter is easy to find, BTW, and would seem more relevant in an actual test situation.)

Comment: Thanks @whuber for the links. Though, I don't really understand the difference between initial and conditional. If I want for example, the  number of expected new questions at my 3 attempt, is this conditional on the fact that I already had 2 quizzes?

Comment: Suppose after several rounds you have seen all the questions.  The conditional expectation of the number of new ones is zero.  The unconditional expectation is what you would guess before starting the quiz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each question has a probability $1-g/n$ of not being picked in each  iteration.  Hence after the $i$'th iteration (letting $i=0$ denote the first iteration), each question has not been picked with probability $(1-g/n)^{i+1}$.  The total number of questions not picked after round $i$, say $Y_i$, thus has expectation $E Y_i=n(1-g/n)^{i+1}$.  The number of new questions at iteration $i$ is $X_i=Y_{i-1}-Y_i$.  Thus
$$
E X_i = n(1-g/n)^{i}-n(1-g/n)^{i+1} = g(1-g/n)^i.
$$

Comment: Fantastic. I saw that this https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/364754/need-help-with-expected-value-calculation-in-coupon-collectors-in-coupon-collect?rq=1 had some similarities but couldn't connect the dots. Thanks.