# What is expected times of sampling that a full population is covered?

Tags: probability, sampling, expected-value

There is a population with `N` instances.

A sampling means we draw randomly `M` instances from the population without replacement.

Two samplings are independent, i.e. after one sampling we push back `M` instances to the pool and restart.

Call `m` is the number of sampling time as each instance in the population has been sampled at least once.

What is the expected value of `m`?

Comment: A variant on the coupon collector problem, (which may prove useful in jumping to a solution...).

Comment: The full distribution is given at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/320152/hard-probability-problem-how-to-calculate-the-the-probability-of-having-selecte/320206#320206.  From there it's a short (easier) calculation to obtain the expectation.  (cc @Glen_b)

Answer (score 2):

Out of the $X_t=j$ unsampled units at time $t$, the number that are still unsampled at time $t+1$ follows a hypergeometric distribution with parameters $N$, $N-M$ and $i$.  The transition probabilities of this [Markov chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain) are thus given by
$$
p_{ij}=P(X_{t+1}=j|X_t=i)=\frac{{i \choose j}{N-i \choose N-M-j}}{{N \choose N-M}}.
$$
Let $k_i$ denote the expected remaining time until all units are sampled given that the current state $X_t=i$.  We then have $k_0=0$ and, from the law of total expectation,
$$
k_i = 1 + \sum_{j=0}^i p_{ij} k_j.
$$
The following R code solves these equations and computes $k_1,k_2,\dots,k_{10}$ for for $M=2$ and $N=10$.

```
expectation <- function(M,N) {
  k <- NULL # k_1, k_2, ... 
  for (i in 1:N) {
    p <- dhyper(1:i, N-M, M, i) # transition probabilities  
    k[i] <- (1 + sum(p[-i]*k))/(1 - p[i]) # solution of k_i = 1 + sum p_ij k_j
  }
  k
}
> expectation(2,10)
 [1]  5.000000  7.352941  8.933824 10.117647 11.065126 11.854557 12.531270
 [8] 13.123362 13.649689 14.123362
```