# Intuition about a coupon problem were we ask for the distribution of the unique coupons when the number of draws is fixed

Tags: probability, self-study, sampling, numerics, coupon-collector-problem

#### Alternative viewpoint of the coupon collectors problem

**In the coupon collectors problem** we draw from a collection of $n$ coupons, with replacement and ask the question how many draws $K$ it takes to collect all or a subset of size $l$ of the coupons (ie, draw $l$ of them at least once). Thus $K$, the number of draws, is the random variable for which a distribution is derived.

**In this problem** we have the the number of draws, $k$, fixed and ask the question how many, $L$, unique coupons we have selected in those draws. Thus $L$, the number of unique coupons, is the random variable.

#### Relation between the two

We can relate these two quantitites via the cumulative distribution functions. The probability that we obtain $l$ or less coupons, given $k$ draws, is equal to the probability that we need to draw more than $k$ times to obtain $l+1$ coupons.

$$P(L \leq l|k) = 1 - P(K \leq k| l+1)$$

#### Question

So basically this question can be answered indirectly with the answer to the coupon collectors problem. That problem has an intuitive and straightforward [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48396/how-often-do-you-have-to-roll-a-6-sided-die-to-obtain-every-number-at-least-once), since the distribution of the number of times to collect $l$ coupons is equal to the sum of $l$ geometric distributed variables.

**Question:** Can we also describe a similar straightforward derivation more directly for $P(L=l|k)$ by *not* using the equation $P(L \leq l|k) = 1 - P(K \leq k| l+1)$?

Comment: I think what you describe is the generalized coupon problem: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/320206/77222 or https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/393638/77222

Comment: @Jarle Thank you for those links.  This *is* the Coupon Collector problem: it is tantamount to asking for the distribution of the number of attempts needed to complete the collection of coupons.

Comment: @whuber Ah, yes, you're right, my bad!  A missed the fact that only a single ball is drawn each time.

Comment: @whuber while the references help, it is slightly different from the coupon collectors problem. In this problem, the number of draws is fixed.

Comment: Yes, but you can read the answer directly off the references.  Do you really need the same information to be derived and explained again?

Comment: Given this was a self-study question, I was working on an answer that explained it more intuitively (sort of using the answer/question as a notepad and I posted it to see if others had easy solutions, but the links to the coupon collectors problem, that change the dependent and independent variable are not so intuitive). So now I can use  P(coupons<=k|waiting_time=t) = 1-P(waiting_time>t| coupons=k), but I had wished to derive it in some more direct way.

Comment: I admire your efforts to distinguish your question from the others.