# What is the waiting time in a coupon collector problem with coupons in packs?

Tags: coupon-collector-problem

I am looking for an equation that will let me calculate the waiting time expectation and variance for a coupon collector problem (equal probabilities of coupons) in which coupons come in packs, with no duplicates within a pack. I found a paper by Stadje (1990, The collector's problem with group drawings) but couldn't get through the math.

I want this for a biology problem in which, say I have $20$ ($s$) insects moving randomly in groups of $4$ ($m$) and they can form all possible groups, how many encounters will it take on average for one insect to meet 18 ($n=l$) of the other 19. I would like to calculate the expected time and $95\%$ CI for varying $s$ and $n$.

I saw a similar question at [How many stickers do I need to complete my FIFA Panini album?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/101255/how-many-stickers-do-i-need-to-complete-my-fifa-panini-album) but that does not have the waiting time equation. Thanks very much. V

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "moving randomly in groups of 4"? Do they change groups periodically?  If so, according to what mechanism or probability law?  If not, then what's the point of the groups in the first place? It's crucial that you are clear about that, for otherwise this question is not sufficiently well posed to be answerable.  Note that a CI is not applicable here: perhaps you want a probability interval.

Comment: Yes, individuals can change groups randomly. Sorry if the question is not clear, but can you at least answer the question if it just pertained to stickers in boxes with multiple stickers (m) arriving each time? I want to know what the waiting time to get l out of s stickers will be for differing s and l. And what the variance around that will be. Thanks.

Comment: I still cannot answer it, because "change groups randomly" is not specific enough to develop any definite answer.  You need to stipulate how often a change occurs, what kind of change occurs, and with what probability.

Comment: Can you ignore the multiple stickers in a cereal box question? Ignore the groups and insects. What is the expectation of waiting time then to get l out of s stickers for differing s and l?

Comment: Sorry, meant can you answer the sticker question and ignore the groups and insects.

Comment: The answers in the [Pannini problem](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/101255) give formulas for the full distribution, so all you need to do is apply them.

Comment: I am voting to close this question. I would like to tackle this problem but the process of 'moving randomly' is left open to interpretation. It is also undefined what an 'encounter' means, which is paramount to be able to state the waiting time, which is requested to be expressed in terms of number of encounters.