# Probability of bad milk

Tags: frequency, coupon-collector-problem

Assume there are (always) $N$ bottles of milk on the grocery shelf. Each day, a deliveryman randomly selects a fixed $M \lt N$ bottles of milk from the shelf and replaces them with new bottles of milk. All milk bottles are date stamped with the delivery date. A bottle of milk is expired after $d$ days.

Assume this has been going on for enough time to have uniform mixing. If I randomly select 1 milk bottle, what is that chance that is is expired? That is, what is the chance that my randomly selected milk bottle has a date stamp more than $d$ days old?

This has similarities to the Birthday Problem, but is not quite the same because of the ongoing batch replacement.

The underlying problem I'm trying to solve has:

- $N \approx 10^9$
- $M \approx 10^6$
- $d \approx 5$

Comment: I don't see any connection with the Birthday Problem, but this appears to be readily translated into the version of the Coupon Collector's problem where coupons (of $N$ distinct types) are collected in batches of $M$: see http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/101255.  Your question asks how many coupons are not collected after $d$ packets are purchased.

Comment: BTW, with the numbers you provide, since $dM \ll N$, the chance of getting an expired bottle will be nearly $1$. A first-order approximation gives $1 - dM/N \approx 0.995$.  Do you really need greater accuracy than that?