# Understanding the equation for the coupon collector problem

Tags: probability, coupon-collector-problem

I am collecting the new world cup panini album. The album has 680 stickers (approx) and there are 5 different stickers in each packet. I would like to know the probability I have of missing 50 sticker after buying 300 packets.

[This answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/101260/) by @eqperes
 shows an analytical solution based on "The collectors problem with group drawings" by Wolfgang Stadje that I can use, but I don't fully understand the equation:

$$ P\big(X_{k}\small{(A)}\! =\! n\big) = {l \choose n} \sum_{j=0}^{n}(-1)^j {n \choose j}\Bigg[{s+n-l-j \choose m}\bigg{/}{s \choose m}\Bigg]^k $$

This is the associated description in that answer:

> $S$ would be the set of all possible stickers, $s = |S|$. $A \subset S$ would be the subset that interests you (in the OP, $A = S$), and $l = |A|$. We're going to draw, with replacement, $k$ random subsets of $m$ different stickers. $X_{k}(A)$ will be the number of elements of $A$ that appear in at least one of those subsets.

What is the difference between the variables $n$ and $l$ in the equation?

Comment: At present, your title is almost identical to the post you link to, but your question is a bit different. In general, it's a good idea to make the distinction clearer (or it may get flagged as a duplicate), and include any equations that you are trying to understand.

Comment: I've now made several edits that hopefully capture your intended question. Please check it to make sure this is what you were trying to ask.