# Cracking a safe: matching $n$ unique numbers with $d$ dice. What is the expected number of rolls?

Tags: conditional-expectation, dice

This problem is inspired by the board game Burgle Bros.

In the game there are safes to crack. You have to match $n$ unique numbers with $d$ dice, where $n = 1,...,6$ and $d=1,2,...$.

For example, suppose the sequence to match is $\{1,3,3,6\}$ and you have $d=2$ dice. There are $n=3$ unique numbers.

---

Edit to clarify rules:

For the example above, let $N=\{1,3,3,6\}$ (for ease of notation). Consider the following rolls:

- The dice rolls are $\{1,4\}$. There is 1 match ($1 \in N$)
- The second dice roll is $\{4,5\}$. There are no matches
- The third dice roll is $\{1,3\}$. There is only one match, as 1 was matched before and $3 \in N$
- The fourth dice roll is $\{6,6\}$. This matches the final element

In this example, the number of dice rolls was 4, so $X=4$. So we stop when we have rolled each number in $N$ at least once.

---

I'm trying to work out the expected number of rolls, $X$, until the code is matched. I know that $E(X|n=1,d=1) = 6$, as $X$ is simply a Geometric distribution. I can also see that for $n=6, d=1, E(X) = 14.7$ under the [Coupon collector's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem)

My question is, **What is a general expression for $E(X|n,d)$?**

Comment: I suspect that $E(X|n,d) = nH_n/d$, where $H_n$ is the $n$th harmonic number, $1/1+1/2+...+1/n$.

Comment: Could you clarify the rules?  It isn't at all evident what it means to "match" the code with dice.  Do you have to obtain the set of unique numbers in the sequence with the dice? Do you have to reproduce the sequence in the code with the rolls?  How do you match *two* dice to a code?

Comment: Hi @whuber. I've added a concrete example that should help clarify the situation.

Comment: Thank you.  That reveals it as a generalization of https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/101255 where, instead of collecting each of a set of "stickers," you have to collect a given number (zero or greater) of each sticker and your stickers come in packets of two (which may contain duplicates). It seems pointless to specify two dice are tossed: just keep tossing one die until the required stickers are collected and divide the count by two (rounding up). That there are three unique numbers to collect isn't really relevant: the specific counts matter.