# Formalizing a Problem & calculating the probabilities

Tags: probability, distributions, confidence-interval

I'm having some trouble formalizing a problem I came up with recently and calculating the corresponding probabilities. I don't know if this is part of a well-known category of problems in statistics, I have been unsuccessful at googling it. If you have some references I'm super interested.

Suppose we draw a fixed number N of numbers in an interval let's say [0,100]. We assume here that all numbers are different when drawn this way. We repeat the experiment k times; each time we repeat the experiment, the entirety of the interval [0,100] is available.
Let's call Y the RV associated with the number of distinct numbers drawn after k experiments.

For the basic case k=1 we have P(Y=N)=1 and P(Y!=N)=0 as N distinct numbers are drawn each time

**given k, I'd like to calculate the conditional probability that Y is above a certain number i.e. P(Y>=m|k) for m∈[[0,100]]. Or conversely given m and p∈[0,100], find k so that P(Y>=m|k)>p%.**

To illustrate the problem in less abstract terms, in two dimensions one could think of some fixed amount of paint being cast randomly on a given surface at regular intervals and then wonder how much time (k) would be necessary for m% of the surface being covered by paint.

I feel my description of the problem is a bit handwavy and I would be super grateful if you could introduce a more mathy/statistical framework, or point me toward some good material. I have the gut feeling that this is a special illustration of a more general theory in statistics (for instance instead of being discrete the variables could be continuous, instead of having a uniform discrete distribution X could have a more complex one etc.).
Thanks in advance for your insights!

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/101255 computes the expectation.  https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/101260/919 quotes a formula for the probability function (summing that will answer your question).  For more details and other variants of this question, please see our posts about the [tag:coupon-collector-problem].